# Mapbox Offlne (Android)

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm working on MapBox off line. The code was OK, able to download map but after adding some peice of code which have nothing to do with the map, the download stop to work and the give an HTTP401 Error.
I've noticed that depending on where you call  MapboxAccountManager.start sometimes it fails. 
Here's the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    DB_Handler db_ansb = new DB_Handler(Init_Carte.this,null,null,1);

    // Get data from DB, about the map
    HashMap<String, String> data_mapbox = db_ansb.do_get_mapbox(0);
    the_mapbox_token = data_mapbox.get("tmapbox_token");
    the_mapbox_style = data_mapbox.get("tmapbox_style");
    the_mapbox_zoom_min = Integer.parseInt(data_mapbox.get("tmapbox_zoom_min"));
    the_mapbox_zoom_max = Integer.parseInt(data_mapbox.get("tmapbox_zoom_max"));
    the_mapbox_inter = Double.parseDouble(data_mapbox.get("tmapbox_inter"));

    OfflineManager offlineManager = OfflineManager.getInstance(this);
    MapboxAccountManager.start(this,the_mapbox_token);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_init_carte);


    // Menu with APP compat
    // https://developer.android.com/training/appbar/setting-up.html
    Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

    // Find our truck GPS position for road map
    HashMap<String, String> my_truck = db_ansb.do_get_my_truck();
    String str_truck_lagps = my_truck.get("frota_lagps");
    String str_truck_logps = my_truck.get("frota_logps");
    the_lagps_truck = Double.parseDouble(str_truck_lagps);
    the_logps_truck = Double.parseDouble(str_truck_logps);

    // Find accident location for road map
    HashMap<String, String> my_inter = db_ansb.do_get_inter_resume();
    String str_inter_lagps = my_inter.get("inter_lagps");
    String str_inter_logps = my_inter.get("inter_logps");
    the_lagps_inter = Double.parseDouble(str_inter_lagps);
    the_logps_inter = Double.parseDouble(str_inter_logps);

    // Compute area to get
    HashMap<String, Double> data_gps_inter = db_ansb.do_get_bounds_inter(the_lagps_inter,the_logps_inter,the_mapbox_inter);
    final double inter_lagps_ne = data_gps_inter.get("inter_max_lagps"); // Nord Est
    final double inter_logps_ne = data_gps_inter.get("inter_max_logps");
    final double inter_lagps_so = data_gps_inter.get("inter_min_lagps"); // Sud Ouest
    final double inter_logps_so = data_gps_inter.get("inter_min_logps");

     // Display what we're doing
    tmp_id_msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_action);
    tmp_id_msg.setText(R.string.str_telechargement_carte);

    // Create zone
    LatLngBounds latLngBounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder()
            .include(new LatLng(inter_lagps_ne, inter_logps_ne)) // Northeast
            .include(new LatLng(inter_lagps_so, inter_logps_so)) // Southwest
            .build();

    OfflineTilePyramidRegionDefinition definition = new OfflineTilePyramidRegionDefinition(
            the_mapbox_style,
            latLngBounds,
            the_mapbox_zoom_min,
            the_mapbox_zoom_max,
            (Init_Carte.this).getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);

    byte[] metadata;
    try
    {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put(JSON_FIELD_REGION_NAME, "Carte");
        String json = jsonObject.toString();
        metadata = json.getBytes(JSON_CHARSET);
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("TAG", "Failed to encode metadata: " + e.getMessage());
        metadata = null;
    }

    // Get data
    offlineManager.createOfflineRegion(definition, metadata, new OfflineManager.CreateOfflineRegionCallback()
    {
        @Override
        public void onCreate(OfflineRegion offlineRegion)
        {
            offlineRegion.setDownloadState(OfflineRegion.STATE_ACTIVE);

            // Monitor the download progress using setObserver
            offlineRegion.setObserver(new OfflineRegion.OfflineRegionObserver()
            {
                @Override
                public void onStatusChanged(OfflineRegionStatus status)
                {
                    Log.i("DBUG","onStatusChanged");
                    // Calculate the download percentage and update the progress bar
                    double percentage = status.getRequiredResourceCount() >= 0 ?
                            (100.0 * status.getCompletedResourceCount() / status.getRequiredResourceCount()) :
                            0.0;


                    long long_pourcentage = Math.round(percentage);
                    String str_pourcentage = Long.toString(long_pourcentage)+" %";

                    // Display on screen
                    tmp_id_valeur = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.val_action);
                    tmp_id_valeur.setText(str_pourcentage);

                    Log.i("DBUG",str_pourcentage+"%");

                    if (status.isComplete())
                    {
                        // OK so now, ask the road
                        do_get_trajet();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(OfflineRegionError error)
                {
                    // If an error occurs, print to logcat
                    Log.i("DBUG", "onError reason: " + error.getReason());
                    Log.e("DBUG", "onError message: " + error.getMessage());
                }

                @Override
                public void mapboxTileCountLimitExceeded(long limit)
                {
                    // Notify if offline region exceeds maximum tile count
                    Log.i("DBUG", "Mapbox tile count limit exceeded: " + limit);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String error)
        {
            Log.e("TAG", "Error: " + error);
        }
    });

}
```

I enter the Aysnc part, get 3 or 4 times 
Log.i("DBUG",str_pourcentage+"%"); 
with a value of 0% then get I get:

I/System.out: [CDS]rx timeout:10000
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x619629c8 sslWrite buf=0x41e60068 len=222 write_timeout_millis=0
D/NativeCrypto: ssl=0x619629c8 sslRead buf=0x41e60068 len=8192,timeo=10000
I/DBUG: onError reason: REASON_OTHER
E/DBUG: onError message: HTTP status code 401
D/com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.http.HTTPRequest: [HTTP] Request with response code = 401: Unauthorized

I've noticed same strange behaviour on another page: depending on the fact you perform or not, action before of after         MapboxAccountManager.start(this,the_mapbox_token); it works or not.

Notice the token is correct.

Any idea?

After changing the token in our DB, it was OK but only for a short time: I was able to download 26% of the map and then, I get again the HTTP 401 message...

Comment: A few questions and suggestions: What version of the Mapbox SDK are you using? Where is the DB_Handler getting data from? If it is using a Sqlite database you should not be calling it from the UI thread as it will involve file access. I suggest you log the value returned for the Mapbox token. Before creating the offline region and starting the download you should check whether it already exists in the offline database.

Comment: We use com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:4.1.1@aar. The DB_Handler came from our lib and get data from SQLLite. No problem with that. The SQL call are not inside the Async. They're done before. We delete the region in another Activity so here, we have only creation. In fact we notice stranger problem wih the lib, probably due to the fact Android is full of async. Eg seems you can init the Lib and BEFORE init is finished, call functions. Which of course don't like that... If i onStatusChanged I put a lot of think, I get a lot of problem. Still investigating... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found. In fact there is a small mistake in the code that help me understand: how can this code work sometimes, as I call

```
  OfflineManager offlineManager = OfflineManager.getInstance(this);
  MapboxAccountManager.start(this,the_mapbox_token);
```

so as I call the init after the use of the Lib? In fact all example at Mapbox are made with one activity performing all the jobs. So when you have more than one activity using Mapbox, you quickly believe you need to put a MapboxAccountManager.start in each ones. Which is wrong. In that case (more than one activity), you must call MapboxAccountManager.start at App level. Like that:

```
public class App_Start extends Application
{
@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();
    String the_mapbox_token = "pk.eyJ1IjoiYW5.....";
    MapboxAccountManager.start(this,the_mapbox_token);
}

public void customAppMethod()
{
    // Custom application method
}

}
```

and add this class at application level on your Manifest:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:name="net.ansb_brasil.xxxx.App_Start">
```

Concerning the fact the second activity was performing two times the download, it came from the fact the  *if (status.isComplete())* part of the onStatusChanged() is always called two times. Seems to be a bug in the Lib. On some example at Mapbox, they use a boolean flag in order to avoid taking two times this call in account.
As my first activity was downloading one map and then call a second activity for a second map, this "double call" had as result two call for the second activity and so many troubles.

Hope this will avoid headaches to others